# Apache basic authentication realm not working with fastcgi

Tags: apache-2.4, realm

I've 2 applications running on same Apache.

1. using fastcgi
2. using Apache basic authentication.

I hope to make app 2 skip user login if user is authenticated to app1.
Can see REMOTE_USER defined after login app1.

I put following in app2 using same AuthName as app1, tried to put under Directory or Location but both don't work:

AuthName "App1 authentication realm"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/htpasswd
Require valid-user

Apache keeps prompting for user login when accessing app2.
I'm afraid I misunderstood/missed some configuration options.
Please help.

I'm new to Apache and apologize for the newbie question.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please provide the relevant config.